# What are these low voltage connectors?

Tags: connector, identification

Can anyone help me identify the kind of connectors in the pics below? Both the male and the female version. In case it helps, these are used in an LED fixture, to connect the (DC) output of the LED driver to the LEDs themselves. They are relatively small, roughly 15mm by 5mm by 2mm.

[image: img1]
[image: img2]
[image: img3]
[image: img4]

Comment: Looks vaguely reminiscent of Molex connectors used for old hard drives, but I don't think it's the same series.

Comment: @Felthry  This a different family than the Molex connectors for HDD power.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Molex econolatch connectors. See part number molex 1501781020 for the 2 pin female.